# How to add constraints in glm.fit in R

Tags: r, constraints, glm

I'm trying to calculate teams' ratings from the final score using the English Premier League 2022-2023 as a data set. It's a 380x4 data frame relative to 380 matches and the 4 columns are Home Team, Away Team, Home score, Away score respectively.

```
# Load the data
data_set = read.csv('https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/E0.csv')
data_set = data_set[, c('HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG')]
head(data_set)
```

This is my formula for the scores.

```
home_advantage + home_team_rating - away_team_rating = home_score - away_score
```

Here it's a bit difficult to explain my idea (but you will get it by running the code). In general, I want all `ratings` sum up to 0 and the `home advantage` must be greater than 0.

I create a 380x20 matrix where the columns are the home_advantage and teams' ratings coefficients. I put 1 for home_advantage. Next, if team A plays against team B, then put a number 1 for team A, -1 for team B and 0 for the rest. Below is the code

```
# I'm sorry if my explanation is unclear, you can just run the code, have a look at the ratings matrix and you will see my point.

all_teams = unique(data_set$HomeTeam)
team1 = data_set$HomeTeam
team2 = data_set$AwayTeam
n_teams = length(all_teams)
team1 = c(team1)
team2 = c(team2) 

goals1 = data_set$FTHG
goals2 = data_set$FTAG

yy = c(goals1 - goals2)

# Ratings dummy matrix
ratings = matrix(0, nrow = length(goals2),
                 ncol = (n_teams-1))

colnames(ratings) = all_teams[-1]

for (ii in 2:n_teams){

  t1_idx = team1 == all_teams[ii]
  t2_idx = team2 == all_teams[ii]
  ratings[t1_idx, all_teams[ii]] = 1
  ratings[t2_idx, all_teams[ii]] = -1
}

ratings = cbind(hfa = rep(1:0, each=length(goals2)), ratings) # add home field advantage
ratings
```

Now I'm going to solve it as

```
glm_res = stats::glm.fit(x=ratings, y=yy,
                         start=c(mean(yy + 0.05), rep(0, ncol(ratings)-1)),
                         family=stats::gaussian(link='log'),
                         control = list(maxit=100, epsilon = 1e-9),
                         intercept = FALSE)
```

Checking the result, you will definitely notice that it got wrong since the home advantage is negative and sum of ratings isn't zero.

```
glm_res$coefficients
```

I want to add two constraints, one is that the home advantage must be greater than zero and all the ratings should sum up to 0. How can I do that in R?